# C# Regex Validate two names or more

Tags: c#, regex

Good Afternoon,

I would like a regex to validate if the user typed two names or more and not only the first name, as in this example:

Ex: Fabrício (no match)

Ex: 
Fabrício Oliveira (match)
Fabrício Oliveira Xavier (match)

Note: The expression must contain accents

Comment: Relevant: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: Cant Madonna, Prince (yes, I know he's dead) or Beyoncé join your club?

Comment: So your requirement is that the characters are valid name characters and there is a space?  What about "Mary Ann"?  That might just be a first name or a first and middle?

Comment: The idea is only validate if the user types two names or more in the field. "Fabrício Oliveira"

Comment: What about `"\S+\s+\S+"`?  That's one or more non-whitespace characters, one or more whitespace characters, then one or more non-whitespace characters.  Feel free to substitute `\S` with whatever character class you deem valid for names.

Comment: \S+\s+\S+ works! But, I wanted the expression does not match if the user enters only first name. Ex: "Fabrício".

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/regular-expressions-understanding-sequence-repetition-and-grouping/#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Regex that only relies on a whitespace separator:

```
^\S+(\s\S+)+$
```

It makes these assumptions:

- No name has a space, tab, or newline in it
- Names are separated by exactly one space, tab, or newline

* *this is based on @juharr's comment but with the parentheses to allow more than two names.*

Edit: You can play around with this Regex here https://regex101.com/r/nS3hN8/1

Edit2: Added the beginning and ending anchors to the regex

Comment: Thanks!!!! It Works!!

Comment: A simpler equivalent pattern would be `\S\s\S`

Comment: @p.s.w.g, it's funny, I was so sure your answer was wrong until I tried a few examples.  I like your pattern better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression which matches two any length words separated by a space:

```
new Regex(@"\w+ \w+");
```

Comment: So "John O'Connor" isn't a name?  It doesn't even work with "Fabrício Oliveira" because of the accents.

Comment: Yes "John O'Connor" is a name. The expression does not match if the user enters only first name. Ex: "John".

Comment: Works for John O'Connor on my box

Answer (score 0):

Really you could just use this:

```
if (Regex.Match(stringname, @"\w+\s\w+").Success)
```